# A Finite Summation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis, summation

Is there an easy way to find the following summation (question created by Priyanshu Mishra on Brilliant.org, but now has been deleted):

$$\sum _{n=2}^{25}
   \frac{(n+1)!-n!}{n^{18}+n^{17}+n^{15}}$$

I have been stuck on this question for a while.  I have tried telescoping and summation by parts, but made no progress.  Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: I doubt that this sum has a nice closed form (or a nice way of computing it). That must be why it has been deleted from wherever.

Comment: I bet that final exponent was supposed to be $n^{16}$.

Comment: Is there a nice way to estimate it to, say, three decimal places?

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt that this is something you'd want to do by hand.
Maple and Wolfram Alpha say
 the result is

$$ {\frac{
860312946581793576829589613997679636863457539755692140640402269050857341143927873402712932016607049546384028604294255522653623852973604499439868106674243290360102696806922095841427559861589
}{
30876129325722069841625830877268487430688400414991976758477334568760877469181887379633764192042605720909025099771337588301198022884091684157065519211912371212685148160000000000000000000000
}}
$$

EDIT: To make this easier to see:
$$ \eqalign{&860312946581793576829589613997679636863457539755692140640402269\cr
&050857341143927873402712932016607049546384028604294255522653623\cr
&\frac{852973604499439868106674243290360102696806922095841427559861589}
{308761293257220698416258308772684874306884004149919767584773345}\cr
&687608774691818873796337641920426057209090250997713375883011980\cr
&22884091684157065519211912371212685148160000000000000000000000}$$

Comment: The fraction that broke MathJax...

Comment: It didn''t break anything, it just doesn't fit in the window...

Comment: Is there a nice way to estimate it to, say, three decimal places?

Comment: The inverse symbolic calculator didn't find anything.

Comment: The last three terms contribute more than $99.9\%$ of the total, so you could just use those.

Comment: The term for $n$ is $$\frac{n!}{n^{17}+ n^{16}-n^{14}} \sim n^{n-33/2} e^{-n} \left(\sqrt{2\pi} - \frac{11 \sqrt{2\pi}}{12 n} + \frac{265 \sqrt{2\pi}}{288 n^2} + \ldots \right)$$